# back goes to two steps back in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, back

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have managing session concepts.

DetailDescription.class having one submit button.if i have to click this button it goes to LoginPage.class.if customer successfully logged in means its go to AddList.class  .

i have to click back button means it should again go to LoginPage.class only.But i want to go to DetailDescription.class with that old data.How can i do this?

**AddList.class:**

```
back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddList.this,DetailDescription.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

the DetailDescription.class having 2 textviews with datas.

```
prod_name.setText(product_title);
        pass_categoriesname.setText(subcategory_title);
```

Now i have to run the app :

The textview values displaying dynamically getting from xml feed depands upon product_id.

Now i have to click submit button its go to LoginPage.

if successful login means its go to AddList.class.

Now i have to click back button on AddList.class means its go to DetailDescription.class with that old data.

How can i do ????

Please give me solution ...

Comment: u must have used finish() in application

Comment: probably you have either finish() in your code or android:noHistory="true" in your manifest for your previous activity.

Comment: i have to write the content finish(); means AddList.class go to LoginPage.class.But login is successfull means why i have to to LoginPage.that's why am asking the question like if login is successful means go to DetailDescription.class

Answer (score 0):

Change code of back button

```
back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           finish();
        }
    });
```

In your login activity Change your code something like this

```
Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,AddList.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Better approach:

*Open AddList activity from DetailDescription activity
By using function `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. So that you can handle the return value form AddList activity.
*Then from AddList activity check whether user is login or not.
*If not open the Login activity using `startActivityForResult`. So that you can get a return value from login activity whether user login success full or not. So you can decide further action.
*After adding details form AddList activity you can finish AddList activity by the same time you can passing the result.

Comment: if login is successful means i have to go DetailDescription.class with that successful login person username...i have wrote ur code means its directly go to DetailDescription.class without logged the customer.so again i have to do login the customer.but if login is successful means why am going to do login the customer again.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what a lot of people will tell you, **do not** alter the code of the back button for a task like this. There are more elegant ways of doing it than that, and the more of Google's code you can leave intact the better - it will make for a much better user experience, and there's no point mangling what's already working for you

As far as I can understand from your question (which isn't very clear), the easiest solution for you is going to be to add

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to your manifest for your Login activity - this will mean that once the user has logged in, the back press won't be able to go back to the login screen as its not stored on the back stack, and the app will go to the activity *before* that - `DetailDescription`.

As for saving the data, you should look into `SharedPreferences`, and save the data in the forms when you leave the activity to restore them when you go back in